# Search and Filter

Tags: plugin-development, filters, search

I am needing a search and filter option for a website.

Please take a look at the example on this page, for the type of search and filter feature I am looking for:
https://www.altec.com/inventory/

I like how each section has a drop down menu.
Also, on mobile the entire section is a drop down menu that opens to the additional drop down menus.

To me, the search/filter on this page is very easy to understand.

This plugin is nice, but I do not see how it can "look as nice" as the search/filter on the website example I included above:
https://searchandfilter.com/

I have been looking, but would love to find out if there are any plugins that offer this type of functionality, and look/feel.
Any suggestions for wordpress plugins that these types of features?